# Extract only ip addresses from a txt file an put them into a line

Tags: linux, bash

i have a txt file full of traceroutes and its on this form.

> traceroute to 188.164.206.1 (188.164.206.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte
>   packets
>
> ```
>  1  83.212.10.1 (83.212.10.1)  3.257 ms  4.571 ms *
>
>  2  192.168.199.1 (192.168.199.1)  5.497 ms  3.171 ms  5.537 ms
>
>  3  ihu-1-gw.eier.access-link.grnet.gr (194.177.208.13)  11.188 ms  13.018 ms  11.305 ms
>
>  4  wind.gr-ix.gr (176.126.38.9)  14.421 ms  12.267 ms  14.714 ms
> ```
>
> traceroute to 194.39.121.182 (194.39.121.182), 30 hops max, 60 byte
>   packets
>
> 1  ec2-50-112-0-84.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (50.112.0.84) 
>   2.026 ms  1.986 ms  1.969 ms
>
> 2  100.64.1.149 (100.64.1.149)  1.757 ms 100.64.1.171 (100.64.1.171) 
>   2.006 ms 100.64.1.157 (100.64.1.157)  2.772 ms
>
> 3  * * *
>
> 4  * * *
>
> 5  205.251.232.226 (205.251.232.226)  2.324 ms 205.251.232.166
>   (205.251.232.166)  2.332 ms 205.251.232.226 (205.251.232.226)  2.988
>   ms

Im trying to make a script that will read all the lines of the file and it will copy only the ip adreses that are inside the `(...)` and will transfer them into one line. So every traceroute will be only one line. 
For example the above traceroute will become

```
83.212.10.1 192.168.199.1 194.177.208.13 176.126.38.9
```

I can not think any obvious ways on how to do this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Etan I don't think that the `**` were supposed to be in the output...

Comment: @TomFenech Yeah, I wasn't sure. It was a choice between removing them and possibly destroying the output or leaving them and adding to the desired output. I erred on the side of assuming they weren't trying to mark that line up since they hadn't marked up the traceroute output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
awk -F'[()]' '/^ / {printf "%s ", $2}'
```

Using a standard value for `FS`:

```
awk '/^ / {gsub(/[()]/, "", $3); printf "%s ", $3}'
```

Or not using a regex at all:

```
awk '/^ / {printf "%s ", substr($3, 2, (length($3) - 2))}'
```

Edit: Handle multiple traceroute output in the same file correctly.

```
awk -F'[()]' '/^ / {printf "%s ", $2; next} /^[^[:space:]]/{print ""}'
```

Comment: Thnks for the quick response, the problem is that there are numerous traceroutes in the txt file, and if i run your comands all the traceroutes will be transered in one line and i want every traceroute to be in one line.

Comment: Etan thank you very much, i really apreciate you help.